# What garbage collected language would be recommended to use when creating a FUSE implementation

Tags: unix, programming-languages, binding, fuse

I would like to implement a virtual filesystem using FUSE under Linux and Mac OS X. I have mainly worked in Java and .NET/C#, but also familiar with Python and do write small utilities/shell scripts in Python. Writing is C/C++ is something that I would try to avoid if possible mainly because of lack of experience in the team.

I see from the [FUSE bindings site](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=LanguageBindings) that there are many binding towards different languages, but I'm not sure which one is the most mature. I have a development team around me which also have worked most in Java and C#. On top of that, the environment must have implementations of common cryptographic algorithm such as Rijndael/AES and RSA.

I've considered Mono since we have a lot of client code in C# already, but the binding haven't been updated for a while and I'm a bit concerned about deploying Mono on Mac OS X. Python is an option, but the team isn't too used to Python syntax although I know it. Java is an option, but I concerned about the bindings which seems to be [forked](http://github.com/dtrott/fuse4j) without to much progress.

A last option which I have considered is [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) which has [FUSE binding](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/BindingsStatus), but the documentation and examples are missing. I know that Vala isn't a garbage collected language, but I still consider it an option. Not sure how easy it is to deploy GObject on Mac OS X.

Comment: I can't tell what question you are trying to ask.  "Which language will my team have the most success with?" is not a question we can help you with here.  If you want to know which bindings for FUSE are mature and in current use, that's what you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing fuse fs. I am using python. As for me it is better for this purpose than some static typed language (c# or java) because there is problems with debugging fuse filesystems. You don't have access to stdin/stdout/stderr therefore after mounting you can't see even exceptions. Python is dynamic and it is easier manipulate with tracebacks, exceptions, execution frames, etc in it.

Comment: Which Python implementation do you use? There's a Google Code project and the FusePython.